# JQuery - Which event gets triggered first window.load or document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a definite sequence for these events to trigger?, So that we can write our initialization accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The `ready` event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the `onload` event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded.

So `document.ready` will trigger first and `window.load` will trigger later

Answer (score 0):

The ready event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the onload event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded.

The onload event is a standard event in the DOM, while the ready event is specific to jQuery. The purpose of the ready event is that it should occur as early as possible after the document has loaded, so that code that adds functionality to the elements in the page doesn't have to wait for all content to load.

Please read here
[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)